# how do i enable / disable divs on radio selection

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, show-hide

I have a form where I want to provide 3 options to pay for an event. Each option is a radio button and contains a div with the payment details. I want these divs hidden until a radio button is selected.

I have created a JSfiddle with what I have at present: http://jsfiddle.net/Kvg8M/1/

At the moment, I have managed to get all 3 divs to be hidden and appear at the same time but I want to only show the one set of details depending on the radio selection and hide the others.

Here is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".paymentmethod").click(function () {
        $(".paymentinfo").show('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments and different ways to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the value and show the appropriate DIV.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".paymentmethod").click(function () {
        $(".paymentinfo").hide();
        switch ($(this).val()) {
            case "Direct Deposit":
                $("#pay0").show("slow");
                break;
            case "Credit Card Authorisation":
                $("#pay1").show("slow");
                break;
            case "Cash at FAA Office (In Person)":
                $("#pay2").show("slow");
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/Kvg8M/2/)

Answer (score 2):

I would add a `data-pay` attribute to each input with the value equal to the `id` of the `<div>` you want to show:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" value="Direct Deposit" id="CAT_Custom_249152_0" name="CAT_Custom_249152" class="paymentmethod" data-pay="pay0"/>
<input type="radio" value="Credit Card Authorisation" id="CAT_Custom_249152_1" class="paymentmethod" name="CAT_Custom_249152" data-pay="pay1"/>
<input type="radio" value="Cash at FAA Office (In Person)" id="CAT_Custom_249152_2" class="paymentmethod" name="CAT_Custom_249152" data-pay="pay2"/>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".paymentmethod").click(function () {
    $('.paymentinfo').hide();
    $('#'+$(this).data('pay')).show('slow');
  });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Kvg8M/3/)